# Z-Index and Opacity not working as expected

Tags: css, z-index

I'm trying to make a original tumblr blog theme. This is my first time writing one from scratch, although CSS is not new to me. Z-indexes, however...

In short, on each post, a menu (like, reblog etc buttons...) becomes visible when the cursor hovers over a post. Apologies if my code looks messy.
`header` is the highest element on the entire page. Everything within `h2` is the button menu, so it should be under `header` at all times.

```
#top header{
    font-family:"Open Sans Condensed", sans-serif;
    font-size:3.5em;
    padding:0px;
    margin-top:-8px;
    height:72px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:{color:Base};
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    box-shadow:  1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    -webkit-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
}
    #post h2 {
        float:left;
        width:auto;
        margin:5px 4px -130px -10px;
        opacity:0.0;
        position:relative;
        z-index:2;
        padding-left:5px;
        font-family:"Calibri", sans-serif;
        text-decoration:none;
        -webkit-transition: all .6s ;
        -moz-transition: all .6s ;
        -ms-transition: all .6s ;
        -o-transition: all .6s ;
        transition: all .6s ;
    }

    #post h2 a{
        color: #fff;
        font-family:calibri;
    }

    #post h2 .item{
        width:20px;
        color:#fff;
        background-color:#5C5C5C;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
        padding:3px;
        -webkit-box-shadow:  1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
        box-shadow:  1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        text-align:center;
        -webkit-transition: all .6s ;
            -moz-transition: all .6s ;
            -ms-transition: all .6s ;
            -o-transition: all .6s ;
            transition: all .6s ;
    }

    #post h2 .item:hover{
        background-color:{color:Post Accent};
        -webkit-transition: all .6s ;
            -moz-transition: all .6s ;
            -ms-transition: all .6s ;
            -o-transition: all .6s ;
            transition: all .6s ;
    }    


    #post h2 {
        color:#ccc;
        margin-left:0px;
        opacity:1.0;
        z-index:2!important;
        -webkit-transition: all .6s ;
            -moz-transition: all .6s ;
            -ms-transition: all .6s ;
            -o-transition: all .6s ;
            transition: all .6s ;
    }
```

I appreciate any help! Also feel free to give me any tips related to what you see above.
Thanks!

**Edit**: 
HTML Markup for an example photoset post:

```
<div id="bin">
    <div id="post">
          <h2> <!-- permalink !-->
              <div class="item" style="max-width:auto; width:auto;">{NoteCount} ♫</div>
              <div class="item" style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:0px;">{LikeButton}</div>
              <div class="item">{ReblogButton}</div>
              <div class="item"><a href="{Permalink}">&#8734;</a></div>
          </h2>


          <div id="photoset">
               <div class="photoset">
                        {Photoset}
                </div>
          </div>
          {block:Caption}
              {Caption}
          {/block:Caption}

          <div id="date">
              {TimeAgo}
          </div>
</div>
                </div>
```

**LIVE PREVIEW**
http://pianotheme.tumblr.com/

Comment: Is it really necessary to have your selectors be so long?  Are there instances where `#bin` or `#post` appear outside of `#wrapper`?  It is difficult to diagnose the problem when there's no markup to go with it.  We also like demos (see: http://cssdeck.com/labs).

Comment: The reason why I have such specific selectors is to make the html portion easier for me to code, I'll know exactly where to look. Some people like this idea, some people don't. There are no instances where #bin or #post appear outside of #wrapper.

Comment: Change selectors like `#wrapper #bin #post h2 .item:hover` to `#post h2 .item:hover{`. There's no need to have that long selector as you are using `id`.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what the exact issue is, could you be a little more specific? Also, a Codpen or JSfiddle, or live example might help as well : )

Comment: I should've had a live example ready for you guys. Sorry! Take a look here: http://pianotheme.tumblr.com/ Of course it's not completely done, but that's basically how the design is going to look. Here's where the problem comes in: hover over a post, notice the menu that slides over from the left. Scroll down, and it overlaps the "pianotheme" header. Understand what I mean?

Comment: On a side note, it looks like I'll have to use `absolute` positioning to remove it from the default flow, or else it pushes over the post content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is just that the buttons and things overlap the top header when you scroll, simply put a high z-index on the #top element. E.g.

```
#top {
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Why didn't I think of that? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No probs. I always look for the simplest option first. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Apply `position:relative;` to the `#top header` element with a `z-index:999;`.

Also, you want to make sure you don't have multiple DOM elements with the same `id` value. They should be unique within the DOM...otherwise, you can get some strange behavior.

Comment: No one said he has multiple items with the same ID, in fact, he said the opposite.

Comment: @Madara, feel free to point out where Kitsu explicitly stated in his original post that he did not have elements with the same `id`. The only thing he originally posted was his CSS. I merely pointed out that he might want to make sure that wasn't the case along with giving him something to try. It's good to see Kitsu has now updated his post to include the HTML.

Comment: @fletch: Not in the original post, but in a comment on the question.

Comment: @Madara, you must be reading into a comment, because again there are no instances where Kitsu explicitly mentions the avoidance of duplicate `id` values...but, no worries. I simply included that bit in my original answer as a precautionary check.

Answer (score 0):

You have not got a closing `}` on your top CSS declaration

You do not have any `z-index` declared in your header CSS. You should set `z-index` this and ensure it has a higher value to what is currently set to your `h2`. To ensure that it is always on top you could give it a value of 1000, for testing purposes.

Comment: I just checked my original code, the closing bracket was in there, but or some reason it didn't copy paste in? Anyway, I've fixed the above code now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` works only on non `static` elements. You do have `position: relative` and `z-index: 2` on `h2` but it won't work as nothing else has non-`static` positioning. What effect are you expecting from `h2`? above which element do you want it to be?

Also, bu default `absolute` / `relative` / `static` will always stay above `static` element at same level.

Comment: I've been messing around with my code so much that I've forgotten to add positioning back in. But anyway, at first I tried `absolute` positioning on the header, but that doesn't seem to work, either.